# url parameter for django url pattern is not passed properly

Tags: django, url

An error occurred for the parameter being passed incorrectly

Is that the action setting is wrong? 
Is the url parameter set incorrectly?
and page_user : {{page_user}} category_id : {{category_num}} is printed normally
I'm not sure if it's wrong with the view.

if you kow what is reson thanks for let me know

code:

```
<form method="post" action={% url "wm:new_comment_for_skilpage" user_name=page_user category_id=category_num %}>{% csrf_token %}
..
</form>
```

and url pattern is this

```
path('new_comment_for_skilpage/<str:user_name>/<int:category_id>/' , views.new_comment_for_skilpage, name="new_comment_for_skilpage"),
```

view is this

```
def new_comment_for_skilpage(request, pk):

    user_name = request.GET.get('user_name')

    category_id = request.GET.get('category_id')



    if request.method == 'POST':

        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if comment_form.is_valid():

            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)

            comment.author = user_name

            comment.category_id = category_id

            comment.save()

            return redirect('/wm/myshortcut/'+user_name+"/"+category_id)

    else:

        return redirect('/wm/myshortcut/'+user_name+"/"+category_id)
```

error:

```
TypeError: new_comment_for_skilpage() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_name'
```

Comment: It seems there is no actual key called `user_name`

Comment: {{page_user}} category_id : {{category_num}} is printed normally 
Could you please let me know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def new_comment_for_skilpage(request, user_name, category_id):

    user_name = request.GET.get('user_name')

    category_id = request.GET.get('category_id')



    if request.method == 'POST':

        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if comment_form.is_valid():

            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)

            comment.author = user_name

            comment.category_id = category_id

            comment.save()

            return redirect('/wm/myshortcut/'+user_name+"/"+category_id)

    else:

        return redirect('/wm/myshortcut/'+user_name+"/"+category_id)
```